# Add count down stopwatches in excel based on a time value in col C

Tags: vba, excel

I have NO idea where to start. I need to have times in column C and when I click the run macro button I need a stop watch to start at the column C time and run down. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show a `clock` kind of thing in Excel cells which works like a stopwatch?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample procedure.

```
Sub stopWatch()

Dim startTime As Date
Dim entTime As Date
Dim mins As Long

startTime = Time

'you code here

entTime = Time

mins = DateDiff("n", startTime, entTime)
MsgBox "Difference in minutes" & mins

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW, thanks! I am confused on where to enter the time. I am thinking about adding a MsgBox to have th eused input the total time desired. Once it is entered the clock will count down from then.

Comment: Date variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers that represent dates ranging from 1 January 100 to 31 December 9999 and times from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59. You can enter the time in date variable.